# How to Zoom In/Out image of dimension around 2000*2000 without any lag?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am integrating a city map in one of my app's activity . But due to its large dimensions(2000*2000) it is causing map to load slowly when app starts and when i zoom in/out it causes a delay of about 1-2sec and its not as responsive as i want . I reffered to this [scale-imageview](https://github.com/matabii/scale-imageview-android) ,it is working fine with images of small dimensions (eg 500*500) .How can i make zoom in/out more responsive with images of large dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was happen because the image is too big and need big memory allocation for render that image. 
there is technique to loading large bitmaps efficiently from android developer site. here the link: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

so, to load bitmap more efficient you have to make it loaded with your limited height and weight. You need to use this function :

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
  // Raw height and width of image
  final int height = options.outHeight;
  final int width = options.outWidth;
  int inSampleSize = 1;

  if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

      final int halfHeight = height / 2;
      final int halfWidth = width / 2;

      // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
      // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
      while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
          inSampleSize *= 2;
         }
   }

return inSampleSize;
}
```

and before you set image bitmap, you have to set some options of BitmapFactory options like limiting height and width of bitmap image. In this example you will limiting max-width to 1024px and max-height to 768px. So, Here the code :

```
    // create new BitmapFactory.Options 
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    // calculate inSampleSize, 1024 is your request-width, 768 is your request-height 
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 1024, 768);

    // decode bitmap with inSampleSize set 
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; 

    Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    // set image bitmap after alter bitmap height and width
    imgDetail.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
```

I hope it can help you. :)

Comment: it did helped but i am still not getting the right way to display the map of dimension 2000*2000px such that one can zoom in and zoom out to see clearly .If u can give the link of some example that would be really helpful .Thanks

Comment: as far as I know, bitmap with size 2000*2000px is too big. I have not another way to load it efficiently, it depends on your device's memory. But you can set the size of reqWidth and reqHeight to 1500px * 1500px. If the bitmap showed normally without any problem, you can increase value of reqWidth and reqHeight.

Answer (score -2):

I have used Chris Banes PhotoView: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView
It works perfectly fine for me for images of size 1024x1024px

Also this has some nice features:
Out of the box zooming, using multi-touch and double-tap.
Scrolling, with smooth scrolling fling.
Works perfectly when using used in a scrolling parent (such as ViewPager).
Allows the application to be notified when the displayed Matrix has changed. Useful for when you need to update your UI based on the current zoom/scroll position.
Allows the application to be notified when the user taps on the Photo.

Usage is very simple:

```
// Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

// Set the Drawable displayed
Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

// Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
```